# Development Tools option not visible on Sitecore CMS desktop mode

Tags: cms-only

I recently installed sitecore 9 on my machine, I was trying to create a package out of my local instance. I opened Desktop mode and clicked on sitecore icon at the bottom, but I was not able to see the 'Development Tools' option which we use for Creating and Installing packages.
Any thoughts on these.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This could be an authorization issue. Your user must be an admin or a member of `sitecore\Sitecore Client Developing` to see this option.

Comment: I checked it, I am an Admin user and also a member of 'sitecore\Sitecore Client Developing' but still not seeing Development tools.

Comment: Can you check `/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Right/Development Tools` in the `core` database, make sure it's there and check the access rules on it?